# Using pagination in a React component, without re-rendering the entire component

Tags: reactjs, pagination, redux, react-router, history.js

I've set up pagination(using a 3rd party component) in one of my React components. Each time a page button is clicked, this function is executed:

```
 handlePageChange= (page)=>{
    history.push(`/duplicates?page=${page}`)        
}
```

I'm using "Router" from "react-router-dom", and "createBrowserHistory" from JS history library:

[image]

When the component mounts, i simply extract the "page" query parameter, and dispatch a Redux action, that fetches all relevant data, and puts its in the Redux state:

```
  componentDidMount(){
    this.props.fetch(this.state.activePage)
}
```

The "activePage" is taken from the component state:

```
state={         
     activePage: this.queryParams.page || 1
 }
```

Everything works nicely, with one very fundamental "flaw": Being that i use history.push on every pagination action, the entire component re-mounts. Sure, i can navigate back and forth in my "pages", and even bookmark them, but the fact that the entire component needs to re-render, seems to undermine one of the main purposes of React: Being very efficient, when it comes to DOM manipulations.

Is there any way to setup pagination, without having to choose between history and efficiency?

EDIT: this is the component:

```
import React from 'react';
import _ from "lodash";
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { searchAction, fetchDuplicates } from '../../actions/products';
import DuplicateProduct from './DuplicateProduct';
import Pagination from 'react-js-pagination'
import queryString from 'query-string';
import {history} from '../../routers/AppRouter';



class Duplicates extends React.Component{
     queryParams= queryString.parse(this.props.location.search); 

     state={         
         activePage: this.queryParams.page || 1
     }   



handlePageChange= (page)=>{
    history.push(`/duplicates?page=${page}`)         
}

componentDidMount(){
    this.props.fetch(this.state.activePage)        
}  

render(){      
    console.log(this.queryParams.page)
    return(
      <div>
      <h1>Duplicate Titles</h1>

      <p>number of pages: {this.props.numberOfPages}</p>
      <Pagination
        activePage={parseInt(this.state.activePage)}
        itemsCountPerPage={150}
        totalItemsCount={this.props.numberOfProducts}
        pageRangeDisplayed={10}
        onChange={this.handlePageChange}
        className="pagination"

      />

       <br/>

       {this.props.duplicates.length>0 &&(
         this.props.duplicates[0].map((duplicate_group)=>{
             return (
                 <div  key={duplicate_group[0].id}> 
                     <DuplicateProduct duplicate_group={duplicate_group}/> 
                     <hr/>                     
                 </div>
             )

         })  
       )
        }


      </div>  
    );

};
}

const mapStateToProps= (state)=>({
    duplicates: state.products.duplicates,
    numberOfPages: state.products.numberOfPages,
    numberOfProducts: state.products.numberOfProducts
}) 

const mapDispatchToProps =(dispatch,props)=>({
    fetch: (page)=> dispatch(fetchDuplicates(page))
})


export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Duplicates);
```

This is the PrivateRoute:

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import Header from '../components/Header';

export const PrivateRoute = ({
  isAuthenticated,
  component: Component,
  ...rest
}) => (
    <Route {...rest} component={(props) => (
      isAuthenticated ? (
        <div>
          <Header />
          <Component {...props} />
        </div>
      ) : (
          <Redirect to="/" />
        )
    )} />
  );

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  isAuthenticated: state.auth.isLoggedIn
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(PrivateRoute);
```

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question

Comment: Could you use `history.replace()`?

Comment: Tried it. It made no difference when it comes to my issue, and absolutely broke the navigation...

Comment: react router shouldn't re-render the whole page if the route component doesn't change. what does your component look like? I think it might be more to do with the component than react-router.

Comment: I think your problem lies inside PrivateRoute HOC.

Comment: I've added the code for the component , and the private route

Comment: Arber sylejmani: You were right :-) . For some reason, it was causing this re-rendering of the entire component. Once i switched to <Route>, everything changed.  Looking at the private route, do you have any idea why ?